# Adding Droppables While Dragging Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

The desired behavior:

The user drags an item onto a tree.  Upon hovering over a closed node, the node expands revealing the children.  At this point the user can continue dragging to the child nodes and drop on any of them.

This was working fine.  I use the "over" option of the droppables to expand the node and make the children droppable.

But I needed to add some more features.  First I added a helper for draggables.  Still working fine.  Then I put the draggables and droppables into two different containers (divs).  At this point, the helper would not drag out of the container.  The solution was to set "appendTo: 'body'" on the draggables.  All good...well, not quite.

Now the child nodes are *not* droppable during the current drag operation.  The user must release the current drag and redrag into the desired child node.  If I remove the appendTo option, the problem goes away, but then the helper does not visually move into the droppable container.

Is there some way that I can "wake up" these new droppables to make them immediately droppable?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I got almost same problem solved. In my case when I toggle the node open during dragging a draggable, child items are loaded via ajax and then they are initialized as droppables. Then I have to do this:

```
ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'refreshPositions', true);
var tempFunc = function() {
    if (ui.draggable) {
        ui.draggable.off('drag', tempFunc);
        setTimeout(function() {
            ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'refreshPositions', false);
        }, 100);
    }
};
ui.draggable.on('drag', tempFunc);
```

This makes the draggable have `refreshPositions` option as `true` long enough for the new droppables to join the current drag. You can also have the `refreshPositions` option be `true` during the whole drag, but it gives a performance penalty which I don't want.

I didn't find a way to do it in another way. It would be best if there was a method you could call during the drag just for refreshing the positions, but there isn't.